# PostgreSQLのDockerコンテナにpsqlで接続したい

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose

DockerのコンテナでPostgreSQLのサーバーを立ち上げています。

```
CONTAINER ID        NAMES        　　　　　　　IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
b292a7d3de2d        backend_container        rails             "rails c"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour
b1e3345f625d        postgres_container       postgres          "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 days ago          Up 3 hours          5432/tcp
```

docker-composeでbackend_containerからpostgres_containerへリンクしており、リンクしたコンテナからは `psql -U postgres -h db -d postgres` でアクセスできます。

しかし、ローカル環境（Dockerコンテナをホストしている環境）からはpsqlでアクセスができません。
たとえば、こんなコマンドでトライしています。

```
$ psql -h $(docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" postgres_container) -U postgres -d postgres
```

なお、`docker exec` を使えばログインすることはできています。

```
$ docker exec -it postgres_container psql -U postgres
```

ローカル環境から直接、psqlで接続するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
アクセスコントロールの問題かと思い、いろいろ試してみましたがどうにもうまくいきません。

環境は以下のとおりです。

ホスト: MacBook Pro (OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6)
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1

皆様のお知恵をお貸しいただければ幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

docker実行時にポートを指定していないようです．
docker-compose.ymlにて

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

のように指定する必要があります．

Answer (score 0):

portを指定しても接続できないでしょうか？

```
psql -h $(docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" postgres_container) -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
```

Comment: ポートの問題ではないのです。質問に記述がなくて申し訳ないです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

私も同じような事象に出会ったので、その対策を共有します。
（これで解決するかわかりませんが）

■原因
　宛先ホストが間違っている。

docker-composeすると、閉じたNWになるっぽいので、
　ホストから見えるpostgresqlコンテナのIP　（例：　localhost:5432)と、
　上記NW内から見えるpostgresqlコンテナのIPは異なっています。
　
■対策
　１．以下を実行して、postgresqlコンテナのIPを見つけてください。（「IPAddress」みたいな項目）
　　$docker inspect

２．postgresqlクライアントにて、上記IPを指定して接続してください。

以上です。